# Convert this C# template to VB equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

can anyone please translate this into the equivalent for asp.net MVC with VB please?

(I'm trying to add a template DateTime picker to the Editor templates - and all I can find is the C# version)

```
@model DateTime

Using Date Template

@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()),  new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
```

I get an error at the first curly bracket, advising type or "with" expected.

Thanks for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of C# to vb converters online.   Here is the output from the one I use   Keep in mind that they aren't foolproof, but they do give you at least a starting point.http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Html.TextBox("", [String].Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()), New With { _
Key .[class] = "datefield", _
Key .type = "date" _
})
```

Comment: Thanks Brian - I wasn't sure if Razor would be converted too.

Answer (score 0):

The VB.Net Anonymous Type Syntax uses `New With` and a dot in front of the property names.  Try the following

```
new with { .@class = "datefield", .type = "date"  }
```

Note: I'm not 100% sure if the `.@class` will work with razor.  You may need to escape it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()), New With {.class = "datefield", .type = "date"})
```

You don't need an " @ " in front of the "New With" anonymous type params.